# how I can draw function I can't specify x or y value in x or y

Tags: python, plot

I have `f=sqrt(x**2+y**2) + (2/3) * sqrt(x**2+((5/6)-y)**2)=1`

The task is :

1. Calculate the integral under or in (with random command)
2. Draw the function (draw the points that locate out `f` in blue color)

I succeed in the first task but the drawing look like another
the graphic supposed to be some thing like (twitter egg) shape
but I have another shape

My strategy for solution::

I will set a rectangle `4*4` (from `-1` to `1` on x-axis and same on y-axis)
then I generate random numbers for `x` and `y` between `-1` and `1`
if these numbers have the result that `f>1`.

That is to mean that these are the points that I have to draw in blue.

I did that 
but I got an ellipse instead of a twitter egg.
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import math

## het functie is  sqrt(x**2+y**2) + (2/3)  sqrt(x**2+((5/6)-y)**2)=1

n=10000
#n is hoe veel keer wil je random getaal doen 

# het integraal is van a tot b
a=-1
b=1
# ik wil stelen :::
#rechthoek opp hier is vier ( van -1 to 1 op x-axis en y-axis)
#want ik kan zien dat het max waarde voor x en y is 1 omdat
# meer dan 1 can de VGL niet = één
# het integral for area IN is when VGL<1

goed_list=[]
false_list=[]
import random 
for i in range(1,n):
    x = random.uniform(-1,1)
    y =random.uniform(-1,1)
    if ( math.sqrt( x**2 + y**2 ) + ((2/3)* math.sqrt(x**2+((5/6)-y)**2)) ) < 1 :
        goed_list.append(y)
    else:
        false_list.append(y)
        plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', color='b', ls='')

opp= len(goed_list) / float((n) *4)

print "de integraal van %d tot %d voor functie ( math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) + (2/3)* math.sqrt(x**2+((5/6)-y)**2) ) is %.5f " % ( a,b,opp)
plt.axvline(x=0.,color='k',ls='dashed')
plt.axhline(y=0.,color='k',ls='dashed')

plt.show()
```

Comment: that is what the graphic should look like [link](https://progns.mprog.nl/course/20%20Module%202/40%20Monte%20Carlo/TwitterEiCombi.png) _italic_ **bold** `code`h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent `if` statement. It should be inside `for` loop. Otherwise, it's executed only once.

And change `2/3` to `2/3.0` and `5/6` to `5/6.0`. In Python 2, `2/3` is zero, not 0.666. When both numbers are integers, the result is an integer too.

This is what I got:

[image]

Comment: That's just a formatting issue here, that's why the lines within the `if` are indented twice (or 8 spaces). That doesn't answer his question.

Comment: sure , it is already inside the loop ( but that's appear wrong here )

Comment: the problem that I got ellipse graphic instead of ( twitter egg)

Comment: oh ( that is right I forget the [.0] ) that helped but I still didn't get the (right shape )

Comment: @het.lezen, did you get the same plot as in my answer?

Comment: I got the same but it is thicker  [link](http://s15.postimg.org/5atcg0k7v/figure_1.png) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Just make the window taller so the y axis is bigger. It's all about that.